# QueryInterface for interface VBA._Collection failed

Tags: vba, collections, queryinterface

We are randomly seeing this error during long executions of our system. The error is caught by our alarm system, and we successfully retry, and continue running the system. The only hits we found on Google seem to mention corrupt installations. We do not think this is the case here, since our systems are running, get the error, and can continue running.

Answer (score 0):

Register the .dll file again from a command window by using the below command:

```
regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvbvm60.dll
```